# Why does IE8 show question marks instead of bullets in HTML Password Field?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have a password field in an HTML page that does not display bullets or asterisks when typing the password, but a small box with what appears to be a question mark symbol.

I've tried this in Firefox, and there the normal bullets are shown, just like when entering passwords in other web forms.

Is there a way HTML, CSS, or Javascript can influence what symbols are displayed? We have a fairly complex web framework (Oracle ADF Rich Client), although other applications based on the same framework do not show this behavior.

Comment: Probably has something to do with character encoding.

Comment: It might, but as far as we can tell the page is served in UTF8.

Comment: Are you using different css sheets depending on the browser (for example, ie.css sheets)? If so, I would try changing a FF user agent to IE and see if it is replicated. Also, is this true on multiple computers with different configs (could be a screwed up system config)

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately, I can't easily. Not only the CSS is user agent specific, so is the Javascript and even the HTML, so my app won't even load. This is a property of the Oracle ADF Framework, so no way to work around it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a font issue. IE is trying to render its password-characters using the U+25CF Black Circle character (●, the same one SO uses for its badges), but not finding a glyph for it in the font being used.

This can happen if you've changed the `font-family` of the `<input>` element to a font that doesn't contain a glyph for this character, or if the user has fiddled their `FontSubstitutes` to point `MS Shell Dlg`, the font the IE uses to render form fields by default, to point to something other than “Microsoft Sans Serif” which does contain a glyph for ●.

Firefox has its own font-fallback algorithms separate from the IE/Windows ones, which are more likely to fall back to a different font that contains ●.

Comment: There is something more to this issue: using Calibri, the character U+25CF displays fine in an input with type "text", but the same character U+25CF is displayed as a square with a question mark in the masked text of an input with type "password".

Comment: The behavior of password inputs is inconsistent with regards to missing glyphs in Internet Explorer 8. For text displayed in a text input / other elements (span, div...), there is a chain of fall-back fonts used to look up missing glyphs. If the glyph is not found in the font-family selected in CSS, the glyph is looked up in the default font configured in Internet Options, "Times New Roman" / "Courier New" by default. If the glyph is not found in configured default, it is looked up in another system font. This is not the case in password inputs, which looks more like a bug than a feature.